# Can't disable trackpad in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad

Last night I upgraded to 17.10. So I'm giving a shot at gnome 3. So far I like it. There is just one thing that is bugging the hell out of me.

I can't disable the trackpad, the `fn+F9` (disable trackpad) does show a on screen prompt but only the one with the cross and it does not disable it. It also does not show the trackpad in the settings.
When I go back to cinnamon(my old default) it does still work, so it's not U17.10's fault.

The laptop is a Asus VivoBook ([Specs in Dutch](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1069537/asus-vivobook-s15-s510ua-bq514t/specificaties/))

Where do I start?

[image]

Comment: This is why I like the HP design pattern of having a hard disable switch not a key combo.  Prefer ASUS or MSI generally, but it's a good design pattern.  If you want to start troubleshooting it.  There's a usbhid enumeration and usbhid disable command from the CLI, but I don't remember what it was,  I had to use it to toggle a sketchy touchpad and toggle a touchscreen at one point.

Answer (score 0):

I like `Touchpad Indicator`.

Find it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/

Comment: That works but only if I select the `Xinput` switch. But still `fn+F9` does nothing :S. I'm hoping for a full answer with fn key...